# Gridview last row overlapped with horizontal scrollbar in ie7

Tags: gridview

Here i am going to use following tag with .css but this grid view working in ie8 and mozilla but when i run applicatin in ie7,last row overlapped by horizontal scroll..can any one provide me sollution for this issue

```
<div class="gridControl_container">
<asp:GridView runat="server" CssClass="gridControl" ID="GrdAD" PageSize="10" 
AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
</asp:GridView>
</div
here the css are below
gridControl_container {
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    max-height: inherit; 
    overflow-x: auto  ! important;
   overflow-y: auto  ! important;
    width: 100%;
}
.gridControl {
    border-right: medium none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: similar problem (not yet resolved) here: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7131

Answer (score 0):

Below I added the following style in gridControl_container. Right now its working fine in ie7.

`#padding-bottom:19px;`

Finally the code as by

```
.gridControl_container {
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    clear: both;
    float: left;

    overflow-x: auto  ! important;
    overflow-y: hidden  ! important;
    width: 100%;
        #padding-bottom:19px;

}
```